# Setting a DataBound items Visibility to false?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView with a load of data in, there is an ID associated to the data that I would not like to be visible to the users. All worked fine when all the cells were visible, but as soon as I change the ID DataBound column to false, when I try to access the item in code I get "" instead of it's actual value (that worked perfectly when it was visible).

Is there a reason for this? If not, how should I be approaching this?

Thanks in advance,

Lloyd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the data in hidden columns are not preserved unless the column is visible when binding to the grid.  Try something like the following:

```
myGrid.Columns(0).Visible = True

myGrid.DataSource = myDataSource
myGrid.DataBind()

myGrid.Columns(0).Visible = False
```

Now your column isn't visible, but it contains your ids.

Comment: Why would Microsoft do that? What's up with them?

Comment: But yes it works, thanks for that, will accept tomorrow unless someone comes up with an amazing way of doing it that doesn't make me look like a Visibility setting lunatic to my colleagues!

Comment: I agree, it was very odd of Microsoft to build it this way.  Let me know if you find any better way as well!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why its happening but one solution is to move the value into a hidden field.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood; but if he has 100 rows in his table, he would need 100 hidden fields...right?  If so, that seems like overkill and harder to maintain.